# Transparency in Java

Tags: java, transparency, awt, awtutilities

I've been using the new `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities` class and am intrigued. I got `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities/setWindowOpacity(java.awt.Window window, float f)` to work perfectly, but am now wondering if there is any way to change the opacity of an individual component, such as a `javax.swing.JInternalFrame` or `javax.swing.JButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class TransparentButton extends JButton {
        public TransparentButton(String text) { 
            super(text);
            setOpaque(false); 
        } 

        public void paint(Graphics g) { 
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create(); 
            g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f)); 
            super.paint(g2); 
            g2.dispose(); 
        } 
}
```

Comment: will this work if I have customized my buttons' border, background,a and foreground, already?

Comment: So far as I know it should. The only way to know for sure is to test it out though.